# ClickOnce error: "Cannot write to the registry key." only for some keys

Tags: registry, clickonce

The code below is so basic it's almost irrelevant.  The question is, how is it that my ClickOnce app cannot write the values below, in HKEY_CURRENT_USER mind you, but *can* write values and create subkeys even, in other parts of HKCU? (For example, the Office AddIn registration keys.)  Nothing in permissions suggests this is the case.  Yet I get an access-related exception in the code below.

Any clues?

TIA,
MM

```
Public Const UNINSTALL_KEY As String = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

Dim key As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(UNINSTALL_KEY)
Dim subKey As RegistryKey
Dim subkeyNames() As String = key.GetSubKeyNames()
Dim cmd As String = ""

For Each keyName As String In subkeyNames
    subKey = key.CreateSubKey(keyName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree)
    If (subKey.GetValue(searchValueName) = searchValue) Then
        subKey.SetValue("NoRepair", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
        subKey.SetValue("NoModify", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
        cmd = subKey.GetValue("UninstallString")
    End If
    subKey.Close()
    If cmd <> "" Then Exit For
Next
key.Close()
```

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Cannot write to the registry key.
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.EnsureWriteable()
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKeyInternal(String subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck, Object registrySecurityObj, RegistryOptions registryOptions)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(String subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck)

Comment: Please update your post with relevant information, instead of posting them in a comment.
Did you try to run the application with elevated privileges?

Comment: Not surprisingly it does work when executed with the runas verb, but that's not the point/not a solution.  It *shouldn't* need elevated privileges to write to HKCU, and the user shouldn't need to be an admin to run our app.